# How to build keyword query language for search contains

Tags: sharepoint-search, containspredicate

I want to build a query for searching for a mobilephone in sharepoint.
I used: `*mobilephone*`.

It's not working for this situation:

- Phone: 0123456789
- Request: 789
- --> Not item found.

Can you provide me a search query for this?

Comment: First thing i noticed is there is a space between the colon(:) and the search key, it doesn't work. If that is not the case try putting the value in quotes? Like Phone:"0123456789"

Comment: No, this mean [my data: 0123456789], my request is [`*789*`], It not working.

Comment: You cannot use a wildcard as a prefix, only as a suffix in KQL.

Comment: So, I can not search for 789 for result 0123456789? If it possible, please show me how. Thanks.